# Abnormal transition animation in UINavigationController with custom view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I have subclassed the UINavigationController and added a custom view (the black bar). As a side effect I have to adjust the frame of my viewController's view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` so that it is not covered by my custom view. The problem arises when I push something onto the navigation stack as seen in the image below.

You can find the code for my UINavigationController subclass [here](https://gist.github.com/harinsa/3951e3b2b210b3685c9d)

ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    log.debug("\(self) \n \(self.view.frame)")

    if let nav = self.navigationController as? TabbedNavigationController {
        let height = nav.view.frame.size.height - nav.navigationViewHeight
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: nav.navigationViewHeight , width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: height)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't change the `frame` of `self.view`,  add a `containerView over self.view` and change that frame.

Comment: @iphonic in the navigationController or the viewController?

Comment: I guess you are doing for the ViewController.